# Python Pandas Dataframe Carriage Return and Line Feed Problems

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading data from an API that I can't share.

I have a `dataframe` that looks like this after reading it from the API:

```
col_1     col_2
1         data
2         data
3         data
Steve
4         data
5         data
```

I want everything in row "Steve" to be concatenated with the previous line.

How can I do this? There is some sort of carriage return/line feed problem when I import the data.

Any suggestions?

```
Expected Output:

    col_1     col_2
    1         data
    2         data
    3         data + Steve
    4         data
    5         data
```

I am converting my result from the API to a dataframe by doing this:

```
results = requesgs.get(url, auth, headers, data)
results_data = results.content

rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(results_data.decode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve]? Including expected output?

Comment: Edited Post to include more info

Comment: How do you convert the result from your api to a dataframe?

Comment: edited code to include details about that too

Comment: can you hard-code `results.content` into another variable? you have so many undefined variables, the example isn't reproducible

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the condition to get the line merged with the previous one is that the value in col_2 is null. That condition can be changed according to your specific case.

```
f = pd.isnull(data.loc[:,"col_2"])
data.loc[:,"col_2"] = ["{:s} + {:s}".format(str(x), str(y))
                       if z else str(x)
                       for x, y, z in 
                       zip(data.loc[:,"col_2"], data.loc[:,"col_1"].shift(-1), f.shift(-1, fill_value=False))
                      ]

data = data.loc[~f,:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

I need to create the series f because is going to used both for:

1. merging the "incomplete" lines with the previous ones
2. filtering out the the incomplete lines once the merger is done